# sqlalchemy different children must exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a query which returns all objects which have children matching specified criteria. The trick is that there are multiple criteria which are mutually exclusive, so there must be multiple children. I'm not sure how to express this.

**Model:**

```
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Message'


class MessageRecipient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MessageRecipient'

    recipient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.uid'))
    message_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Message.uid'))

    user = relationship('User', backref="messages_received")
    message = relationship('Message', backref="recipients")
```

I want to get all messages which are being sent to a defined set of users. For example, I want to return all messages which were sent to users `1` and `2`, but not messages only sent to user `1` or messages only sent to user `2`. It must have been sent to both users!

I was trying a query like the following:

```
    query = Message.query.filter(Message.recipients.any(MessageRecipient.recipient_id.in_([1,2])))
```

The above doesn't work because `in_` is disjunctive. It does return the messages I want, but it also returns messages I *don't* want.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can build a query which requires that a `Message` have `MessageRecipients` with an arbitrary set of ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by iterating over all objects in the collection and creating a new subquery for each using `exists()`. Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it works.

```
    for recipient in [1,2]:
        query = query.filter(MessageRecipient.query.filter(and_(MessageRecipient.recipient_id== recipient, 
                                                                MessageRecipient.message_id == Message.uid)).exists())
```